# Removing leading zero and inserting the value in to a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to move all the values of a column to a new column. But I need to remove all leading zeroes before inserting it to the new column. For example, I have '000123' on my original column. I need to update my new column as 123. And I need to to this to a 100,000 rows. Is there a way to do it in a sql query?

```
select substring(ColumnName, patindex('%[^0]%',ColumnName), 10)
```

I've found this code on how to remove the leading zeroes. But how can I insert it into a new column?

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL? AS far as I know `PATINDEX` is a SQL Server function not available in MySQL.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I have heard from several people that the question form is over zealous when suggesting tags and pushes MySQL too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast the value to an unsigned:

```
update <table> set new_column = CAST(ColumnName AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Should I set the new_column as an integer?

Comment: @jejerome That depends on your requirement. But the cast the value to an integer will remove the leading zeros

Comment: @Downvoter: please be fair and explain why, so i can improve my answer

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would be worse with the unexplained downvotes here

Answer (score 3):

You have several options here.  You could just cast your text column to numeric during the update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_col = CAST(ColumnName AS UNSIGNED)
```

But you could also explicitly remove leading zeroes from the text numbers in the column:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_col = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ColumnName)
```

Since it appears you want the new data to behave as numbers, where leading zeroes are artifactual, you might want to make the `new_col` column some numeric type.

Answer (score 2):

Just this should do:

```
UPDATE tablename SET newColumn = currentColumn*1
```

Just set your newColumn to integer, and do not set it to zerofilled (by default, it already isnt).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to move the column (adding new column) then do

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM ColumnName)
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

If you want to update already existing column with new value then

```
update table-A set columnX = 
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM columnX) as columnX
FROM table-A
WHERE condition)
```